# Text Based RPG Functioning Error?

Tags: python, text, python-2.7

So, I'm hard at work on a text-based RPG game on Python 2.7, but I came across a problem in the character menu. Here's what it looks like:

```
def raceselect(n):
            if n==0:
                   print "(name) the Human."
            if n==1:
                   print "(name) the Dwarf."
            if n==2:
                   print "(name) the Elf."
            if n==3:
                   print "(name) the Halfling."
n = raw_input
raceselect(n)
```

0, 1, 2, and 3 are all used as raw_input answers on the previous screen when prompted with the options. However, when the script is run, the options are shown, and the input box shows, however when a number is answered the script simply ends. I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this, unless it's the fact that I used (name) and raw_input earlier in the script, which I doubt. Please help!

--Crux_Haloine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn the raw input into a int:

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

Also, you need to call the function, so use `raw_input()` rather than just `raw_input`

Answer (score 0):

`n = raw_input` here will bring nothing to you. You should use `n = int(raw_input())` according to your need. And I think it is better for you to use a `dict` or `list` rather than several `if`:

```
def raceselect(n):
    races = {0: 'Human', 1: 'Dwarf', 2: 'Elf', 3: 'Halfing'}
    if n in races:
        print '(name) the %s' % races[n]
    else:
        print 'wrong input'
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue is this:

```
n = raw_input
```

You never actually call the function. Instead, your are assigning a reference of `raw_input` to `n` (as in, n is now the function, not the result of the function).

Also, once you call the function, you have to cast it into an integer, because `raw_input` returns a string.

Thus, you want:

`n = int(raw_input())`.